# Persistent cookie not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a problem with persistent cookies in Internet Explorer, that is, I can set the cookies, but cannot make them persist. I'm using Internet Explorer 11, and have tried "Internet Options" -> "Advanced" -> "Reset", but it didn't help.

I've written this test code:

```
class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:7777/");
        listener.Start();

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) = > {
            while (listener.IsListening) {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) = > {
                    HandleRequest(c as HttpListenerContext);
                }, listener.GetContext());
            }
        });

        Console.Write("Press any key to quit . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        listener.Stop();
        listener.Close();
    }

    static void HandleRequest(HttpListenerContext ctx) {
        var cookie = ctx.Request.Cookies["TestCookie"];

        if (cookie == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting cookie...");
            var expiryDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(360);
            ctx.Response.Headers["Set-Cookie"] = "TestCookie=some_value; Path=/; Expires=" + expiryDate.ToString("ddd, dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss") + " GMT; HttpOnly";
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Cookie: " + cookie);
        }
        ReturnString(ctx, "OK");
    }

    protected static void ReturnString(HttpListenerContext ctx, String s) {
        try {
            byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } // suppress any exceptions
        finally {
            // always close the stream
            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when accessing `127.0.0.1:7777`, I first get "Setting cookie", and then "Cookie: TestCookie=some_value" on all subsequent requests. In Chrome the cookie is persistent (I can close the browser, restart it, and still get "Cookie: TestCookie=some_value"), but this doesn't work in Internet Explorer. That is, when using IE, I get the "Setting cookie" on the first request every time I restart the browser. So the cookie is clearly not there anymore.

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong? Surely there must be some way to set persistent cookies in IE using a C# server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I found the answer. It's quite embarrasingly simple, really. When setting expiry date, I used the code

```
expiryDate.ToString("ddd, dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss")
```

but of course this creates a localized representation of the date. And since I'm in Norway, the "ddd" created the day of the week in norwegian. And of course IE was not able to parse that.

This simple change solved the problem:

```
expiryDate.ToString("ddd, dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

So sorry for all your trouble, folks..

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your site to the trusted zone within IE Properties?  This sounds like it could be related to security settings.

Comment: Well, I can go to "Safety" -> "Webpage Privacy Policy" -> click on "127.0.0.1" -> "Summary" and select "Always allow this site to use cookies". That solves the problem, but I don't think I can require regular users to do this. So I'm looking for a way to make this work with IE default settings.

Comment: That's fine.  Was just trying to establish the scenario.  In terms of why it may have been blocked, likely reasons are that it may think the cookie is a third-party cookie (you would see this, for example, if you're setting the cookie to 'localhost', but then navigate to 127.0.0.1), if it's being set from within an iframe, or if the data in the cookie contains information that IE believes  could be used to contact you (e.g. email address).  With IE, it's often worth including a P3P header that tells IE your site is not completely unsafe (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P).  Have you tried P3P?

Comment: I've always used 127.0.0.1, never localhost in my scenario. And no frames. The data is a Base64-encoded string, looks nothing like an email address. I've tried P3P, but have not yet invested enough time to understand it properly, so basically I've just included some P3P stuff I found by googling.

Comment: OK, well the next thing I'd probably try is finding a site that does store a persistent cookie in IE (perhaps SO) via a proxy like Telerik's fiddler, and comparing the headers (specifically the Set-Cookie header) that are sent by that site to the ones coming from your own, to see whether there are any other obvious differences.  I've seen issues in the past, for example, where there are multiple Set-cookie headers for a response that are ignored by some browsers, but read by others, where the second is not persistent and the first is etc.  Worth a check.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to privacy policy. The headers need to be set to allow cookies from other domains.check,

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx